# Cookie return previous value, when called

Tags: php, cookies

I edit the array (json encoded) and try push it on cookie, so when i try to show value of this cookie i get a previous value, not current.

```js
In to json
[["d33d6eb947","XS","5"],["78b33f6c64","XS","1"] 


Set cookies 
[["d33d6eb947","XS","5"]]
```

As you can see array and cookie is different, but i set the cookie with same array.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    function addItem($itemUrl, $itemSize, $itemCount)
    {
        if(isset($_COOKIE["cart"])) 
        {
            $cartItems = json_decode($_COOKIE["cart"]);
        }
        else 
        {
            $cartItems = array();
        }
        $itemsArray = array($itemUrl, $itemSize, $itemCount);
        array_push($cartItems, $itemsArray);
        $cartItems = json_encode($cartItems);
        setcookie("cart", $cartItems, time()+60*60*24);
    }

?>
```

And when i use (for example) print_r($cartItems); i get a array with two (for example) values, but when i use (after setcookie) print_r($_COOKIE["cart"]); i get a array with just one value. When i re-use this function and reload page i get a array with three values and cookie with just two values. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_decode($_COOKIE["cart"], true)` to convert to an array (instead of StdObject).